# Invalid identifier error when creating an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
 NUMBER VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 FEE NUMBER,
);
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

It is showing this error. Can someone help me fix this.

Comment: Gee, if only there were some kind of Engine where someone could Search for things...maybe even error codes, such as `"ORA-00904"`. Bah, that's just a pipe dream...

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove last comma `,` and change the first column's name (to `NUM` for example) below

```
CREATE TABLE Item 
( NUM VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
  FEE NUMBER 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the last comma, before last parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

**NUMBER** is keyword in Oracle . You can not use it as column name in your table destination.

Comment: I am new to this. Can you tell me how to fix this error

Comment: Either choose a different column name or [quoting it seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0b60). The other answers are also correct that the trailing comma will also cause this error.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Item 
( ITEMNUMBER VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
  FEE NUMBER );

Answer (score 2):

I believe NUMBER is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), try a different name for that field